# Bash rm directory with string variable returns jumbled

Tags: linux, bash

I'm making a script...

```
cd /root/downloaded
#take input
read -p 'URL:' url
echo
echo i will convert this file...
echo
#download and send output to temp txt file 
cd /root/
youtube-dl $url --force-ipv4 --exec echo > tempyou.txt 
file=$(tail -1 /root/tempyou.txt)
dir=""$file""
cd /root/go/bin
./gdrive upload "/root/$dir"
cd /root
echo
name="'$dir'"
path=$(pwd ~/$name)
directory="${path}/${name}"
rm $directory
```

that takes a URL input and sends it along to yt-dl to download the file and then sends that along to gdrive that sends that along to my google drive. Downloading and sending the file works but when i try and take variable that has the name of the file saved to my root directory (through a temporary output to a text file with all the names of the videos and the magic of the tail command) the text becomes a chopped up mess...

```
rm: cannot remove "/root/'How": No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'It': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'Feels': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'To': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'Code': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'With': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove "'Brainfuck'-T-qx-oC_lUo.mp4'": No such file or directory
```

RESOLVED: hey guys i fixed my script and made it a bit prettyer, created a temp directory where i place all my temp files and used tail to list the most recently created file, then i found a option after going through gdrive that would delete the file for me after uploading it. heres my code.

```
#!/bin/bash -i
cd /root/tempyt
read -p 'URL:' url
echo
echo i will convert this file...
echo 
youtube-dl $url --force-ipv4
name=$(ls -Art | tail -n 1)
echo "$name"
path="'$name'"
cd /root/go/bin/
./gdrive upload "/root/tempyt/$name" --delete
```

Comment: i did three things, and wrapped the rm up in qoutes as suggested and removed the directory variable because i realized i could just put the path in the rms qoutes. Oh and i tryed your typeset suggestion this is my output... ```declare -- name="'How It Feels To Code With 'Brainfuck'-T-qx-oC_lUo.mp4'"
'How It Feels To Code With 'Brainfuck'-T-qx-oC_lUo.mp4'
rm: cannot remove '/root/{'\''How It Feels To Code With '\''Brainfuck'\''-T-qx-oC_lUo.mp4'\''}': No such file or directory``` better.. but still not even close, you have any idea what the problem is? im a mere bash noobie.

Comment: looks like a lot of unnecessary embedded quotes but need to know the original file name; also, does the `gdrive` call successfully upload the file (ie, have you checked the uploaded file for accuracy?); I'd also suggest updating the question with the code changes you've made, after `file=$(...)` add `typeset -p file` and report the output; and (from the command line): `cd /root; type *Feels*mp4*` and report the output; by 'report' I mean 'update the question with the extra commands and the associated outputs'

Comment: Check your script with shellcheck.net `RESOLVED: hey guys` so post an answer.